# SQL COUNT DISTINCT with condition based on another column

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I'm stuck with this problem and i don't find a solution to it.

I have a table and I want to count the number of parts for each station and error type, but if a part have multiple errors in the same station just count the error which lexicographically is highest.

The data looks like this:

```
| station     |   error   |   uniquepart_id   |
| ----------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| A           | ERR_01    | 0001              |
| A           | ERR_01    | 0001              |
| A           | ERR_02    | 0002              |
| A           | ERR_02    | 0002              |
| A           | ERR_03    | 0001              |
| A           | ERR_03    | 0002              |
| A           | ERR_03    | 0003              |
| A           | ERR_03    | 0004              |
| B           | ERR_01    | 0005              |
| B           | ERR_01    | 0006              |
| B           | ERR_02    | 0007              |
| B           | ERR_02    | 0008              |
| B           | ERR_03    | 0009              |
| B           | ERR_03    | 0010              |
| B           | ERR_03    | 0011              |
| B           | ERR_03    | 0012              |
```

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT station, error, COUNT(DISTINCT uniquepart_id) AS num_parts
       FROM Tablename
       WHERE (process_date= 'xx-xx-xxxx')
       GROUP BY station, error
```

I'm getting this result:

| station | error | num_parts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ERR_01 | 1 |
| A | ERR_02 | 1 |
| A | ERR_03 | 4 |
| B | ERR_01 | 2 |
| B | ERR_02 | 2 |
| B | ERR_03 | 4 |

**and I'm looking for this:**

| station | error | num_parts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ERR_03 | 4 |
| B | ERR_01 | 2 |
| B | ERR_02 | 2 |
| B | ERR_03 | 4 |

I tried to use MAX and HAVING to filter the rows within each of the groups, but I'm getting syntax errors. I think with an inner query could be solved.

Comment: Please share your simple data/expected output as text instead of images so it can be easy to help you

Comment: Can you also tag the DBMS ? is this mysql ?

Comment: Sorry, now is as saved as text and the database is in hadoop

Comment: Your query filters on a column not in your example data. Please read [mre] and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 2):

Process your data in two stages.

First (inner query) collapse your data to one error code per part per station.

Then process as you have been.

```
SELECT
  station, error, COUNT(*) AS num_parts
FROM
(
  SELECT station, MAX(error) AS error, uniquepart_id
    FROM Tablename
   WHERE process_date = 'xx-xx-xxxx'
GROUP BY station, uniquepart_id
)
  AS station_error_per_part
GROUP BY
  station, error
ORDER BY
  station, error
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I knew I needed an inner query but I didn't know how to do connect them.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from
(
SELECT station, error, COUNT(DISTINCT uniquepart_id) AS num_parts
  , dense_rank()over(partition by error order by COUNT(DISTINCT uniquepart_id) desc) rn
FROM test
-- WHERE (process_date= 'xx-xx-xxxx')
GROUP BY station, error
) t
where rn=1
order by station, error
```

Update1: @MatBailie, thank you for a note about the error.

```
select * from
(
SELECT station, error, COUNT(*) AS num_parts
  , dense_rank()over(partition by station,error order by COUNT(*) desc) rn
FROM (SELECT station,uniquepart_id,max(error) error
    FROM test
    -- WHERE (process_date= 'xx-xx-xxxx')
    GROUP BY station,uniquepart_id
  ) p
GROUP BY station, error
) t
where rn=1
order by station, error
```

The rn value is of course superfluous

Comment: Doesn't actually match the requested behaviour; `if a part have multiple errors in the same station just count the error which lexicographically is highest`

Comment: yeah i tried also this query and it is not the result I'm looking for.

Comment: If you group by `station, error` and also partition by `station, error`, each and every window will always consist of exactly one row. Creating, and filtering on, the `rn` column does absolutely nothing.